# Take html whole page

Tags: html, css, iframe

A webpage has 4 images, which are continuously moving or rotating, i want to put web whole page except images I tried with <`iframe src= somewebpage.com width= "1000px" height="400px" position = "relative" scrolling = "no"></iframe>`. It is working for me fine but only one problem when the webpages will display inside a frame only top portion of the page is visible only...
   I want in such a way, when it will take the page from url, it will take the whole page and put it inside the iframe. So i can see the whole page from top to bottom in one shot.. without any scrolling..

Comment: is the page over 400px height?

Comment: I want the whole page in width 1000px and height 400px

Comment: so, it won't fit in 400px height ?  you are asking how to change the proportion to make it fit??

Comment: it is fit, the problem is, suppose a web page(new.html) contain the main info on top and subinfo on bottom. through my html code when i am using the page(new.html) by url only the top main info is comming not the bottom sub info. If i remove scrolling from iframe then by scrolling i can see the whole page. But i do not want scrolling and display the page. i want to see the whole page from top to bottom in one shot.. without any scrolling..

Comment: I'm lost, if it fits why would you have to scroll at all? If it fits the scroll bars shouldn't even appear on the iframe.

Comment: Because without scrolling we can not see the whole page only the top portion is visible

Comment: I have uploaded  the image on "http://imgur.com/ihOGork". I this i can only see half portion of the python web page. I want the whole page without any scrolling

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body
{
width:1000px;
height:400px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Is here any option so i can put the screen shot

Comment: I have uploaded  the image on "http://imgur.com/ihOGork". I this i can only see half portion of the python web page. I want the whole page without any scrolling